# Hot to hide a component when clicking a Custom Button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to hide a component when clicking a Yes or Not. I'm getting the correct output when clicking but the component that acts like a Popup keeps in the screen and I can not remove it.

This is my component

```
export default class MyPopUp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    let { username } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="modal-wrapper">
        <div className="modal">
          Some Text
          <br />
          <MyButton
            name={username}
            surname="pewlas"
            arguments={["yes"]}
          >
            [ Yes ]
          </PostCommandButton>{" "}
          <MyButton
            name={username}
            surname="pewlas"
            arguments={["no"]}
          >
            [ No ]
          </MyButton>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is `MyButton`

```
import { connect } from "react-redux"
import button from "../../../common/components/Button"
import { myButton } from "../actions/myButton"

const MyButton = connect(
  undefined,
  (dispatch, { name, surname, arguments: args = [] }) => ({
    onClick: () => dispatch(button(name, username, args)),
  }),
)(Button)

export default MyButton
```

And this is my button

```
export const MY_BUTTON = "MY_BUTTON"
export const myButton = (name, surname, args) => ({
  type: MY_BUTTON,
  name,
  surname,
  arguments: args,
})
```

How can I hide `MyPopUp` when clicking Yes or No? I do not find the way to link my PopUp component with the onClick from MyButton, how can I add a state so I can show it or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try to help you maybe refactorizing some code.

First of all, I have seen that you are using redux with your Button, to do what you want to do you have some options:

```
    const SURNAME = "pewlas"
export class MyPopUpComponent extends React.Component {
  state = { hidden: false }

  handleClick = value => {
    this.props.myButton(this.props.username, SURNAME, value) //the action creator
    this.setState({ hidden: true }) //**IMPORTANT**
  }

  render() {
    const { username } = this.props

    if (this.state.hidden) {
      return null
    }

    return (
      <div className="modal-wrapper">
        <div className="modal">
          Some Text
        <br />
          <button
            name={username}
            surname={SURNAME}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick("yes")}
          >
            [ Yes ]
        </button>{" "}
          <button
            name={username}
            surname={SURNAME}
            onClick={() => this.handleClick("no")}
          >
            [ No ]
        </button>{" "}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  myButton
}

export const  MyPopUp = connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyPopUpComponent)
```

You can do something like that, first of all, you show the popup initializing state hidden to false. As you can see in the render you are going to show the text with buttons and as soon as a user press yes or now you can launch an action or do whatever you want and after that, you set hidden to true. The state has changed so the render function is called again returning null, hiding the component.

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what should be yes and no? what should I put there? change the state?

Comment: The thing is that I have a Custom button as you can see on my question, how can I make simple to don't show the popup if user clicks yes or not? Yes I have to handle the click so I can hide it, but copying your code is not working what should I put instead of "yes" or "no"? and also inside the handleClick? I only want to change the state so the popup is  false.

Comment: Hi, I think you don't need a custom button. If you want to dispatch an action when the user clicks on yes or no, you just have to pass as many arguments as you need to the handleClick and dispatch there the action. The "launchWhateverYouWant" part that I told you. I'm going to change the code just to be closer than you need.

Comment: Now you connect to redux your popup, when the user clicks on yes or no you are going to dispatch the action MyButton with arguments (username, surname, and "yes" or "no" depending on the pressed button). After that, the state is going to change to hidden and the popup is  not going to be shown

Comment: I can not modify that Samuel... how can I adapt this functionality with this custom button?

Comment: Please could you adapt it to my code from my question please? With my same custom button? shouldn't be possible no don't touch my custombutton and make it on the popup component? So i don't change anything of my old custombutton?

Comment: The problem is that I think that MyButton has an onClick() function so if I call onClick on my MyButton it will call my principal function and the new one?

Comment: Can you take a look on this please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53703230/create-a-select-with-dynamic-values-react-redux